# no errors but yet the app crashes but don't know why

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to display a button in front of all of the canvas in the game I'm making but so I've had to display it .java code instead of .xml code. I'll place the code below.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
        myButton.setId(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings);
        myButton.setClickable(true);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layout_82 = null;
        layout_82 = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                layout_82.height = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                layout_82.width = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(layout_82);

        registerForContextMenu(myButton);
    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat. Let's bet it's an NPE?

Comment: Copy from your logcat view into your question. Select all the pasted text and press `Ctrl` + `+` (or `Option` + `+`, if you're using  a Mac). You have to put some text between your code and the error. I.e.: "Logcat:`ENTER` `ENTER`"

Comment: I mean how do I get the Logcat up. I'm really new to programming

Comment: I don't know in Android Studio, but in Eclipse is on the lower pane, there's a tab called Logcat. I think it's similar in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're probably getting a `NullPointerException` right here:

```
layout_82 = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            layout_82.height = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            layout_82.width = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

When you call `layout_82.width` and `layout_82.height` here, you do so before `layout_82` has been assigned, so it's still `null` from the previous line. Also, this assignment your doing appears to be unnecessary. Try changing that line to this:

```
layout_82 = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```